# ListView into CardView

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I have an app running the new Appcompat V21, and a main activity with a basic list view. Is it possible to turn this basic list view into a card view with an image and the title on each card? (Use the Google+ app for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's actually very easy to do that. As you are already using v21 of the support library you can just wrap your basic list item code in a CardView. Something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Example application"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use recyclerView with a custom adapter.